# I cannot make a table with Material UI in a ReactJS program

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to make a table using MaterialUI in a ReactJS application. Therefore I have imported the modules with the following line, as MaterialUI official website suggests:

```
import {
    Table,
    TableBody,
    TableHeader,
    TableHeaderColumn,
    TableRow,
    TableRowColumn,
  } from 'material-ui/Table';
```

The problem is that when I launch `npm start` it says:

```
Can't resolve 'material-ui/Table in 'C:\Users\myprojectpath\src'
```

Actually in my "node_modules" folder I have a folder named "material-ui-table", moreover Material UI buttons work so Material UI should be properly installed...

Comment: Do individual import lines work? Like this: `import TableBody from 'material-ui/Table/TableBody'`

Comment: Can you use this:
import {
    Table,
    TableBody,
    TableHeader,
    TableHeaderColumn,
    TableRow,
    TableRowColumn
  } from 'material-ui';

Comment: it does not work

Comment: @udayakumar's answer should work. If it doesn't, then post the error message you're getting here.

Comment: Now it says that it can't resolve 'material-ui/core/Button', which it was able to resolve a few hours ago...

Comment: Are you trying to use Material-UI [v0.x (old)](https://v0.material-ui.com/#/components/table) or [v1.x (new)](https://material-ui.com/demos/tables/)? Try making a new project as a test and installing Material-UI from scratch to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Install material-ui using this command :

```
npm install material-ui@latest
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you use this

```
import { 
    Table, 
    TableHead, 
    TableBody, 
    TableCell, 
    TableFooter, 
    TablePagination, 
    TableRow, 
    Paper } from 'material-ui';
```

Here you don't need require it from material-ui/Table as you already defined at inside the scope

**Example:**

```
class Products extends Component {
render() {
return (
<Paper>
   <div>
      <Table>
         <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
               <TableCell>Hi</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
         </TableHead>
         <TableBody>
            <TableRow>
               <TableCell>1</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
         </TableBody>
         <TableFooter>
            <TableRow>
               <TablePagination 
                  colSpan={3}
                  count={5}
                  rowsPerPage={2}
                  page={0}
                  />
            </TableRow>
         </TableFooter>
      </Table>
   </div>
</Paper>
)
}
}
```

Above code is working fine.

Comment: Please don't provide two answers. Edit one or the other to contain all relevant information.